# Pandas python converting a list into a dataframe and count number of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This such a simple problem, which is why it is annoying me to no end that I can't do it.

I have a series of lists that I have converted into a flattened list:

```
myList= []
for i in myList['variable'].tolist():
    for j in i:
        myList.append(j)
        
frequency = pd.DataFrame(myList).reset_index().sort_values(0).groupby(0).count()
```

It's the last line that is letting me down. I don't know why, but it returns a wrongful count of each member of the group.

sample input = `[2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 6, 2]`

expected DataFrame output =

```
var    count
2        3
4        1
6        2
7        1
```

Comment: For starters, your code will error out. Next, please provide sample input / output.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to group by a categorical variable and compute aggregate statistics for each group, pandas can do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': random.choices(range(1,4), k=20),
        'b': np.random.normal(size=20),
    })

df.groupby('a').count()

#     b
# a
# 1   2
# 2   8
# 3  10

df.groupby('a').agg(('count', 'mean', 'std'))

#       b
#   count      mean       std
# a
# 1     2  0.454240  2.218616
# 2     8  0.165295  1.355922
# 3    10 -0.004880  1.225908
```

See: [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

Answer (score 0):

As this website was so helpful, I figured it out.

Test = pd.DataFrame(list)
Frequency = test[0].value_counts()